# Build failed: Please set the environment variable 'LEGACY_NDK' to point to a NDK location with gcc/gfortran support (supported NDK version: 'r21e')

Tags: python, kivy, apk, buildozer

I'm trying to make a kivy app into an apk.
Github actions failed at the last step with the following error:-
[ERROR]:   Build failed: C:\Users\Aadit\Downloads\android-ndk-r26b-windows\android-ndk-r26b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gfortran not found. See https://github.com/mzakharo/android-gfortran
And Google Colab and the Windows Subsystem for Linux return the following error:-
[ERROR]:   Build failed: Please set the environment variable 'LEGACY_NDK' to point to a NDK location with gcc/gfortran support (supported NDK version: 'r21e')

Can someone please help me? Please respond fast.

I was expecting a .apk file, but it always gave an error message. Whether it were github, or google or even the local subsystem. I tried updating the build.yml, I tried writing export LEGACY_NDK=(PATH TO/android-ndk-r21e) in the wsl, cmd. I tried adding an environment variable called "LEGACY_NDK", and put the windows style path, then linux style path. I put the path to my android ndk in the buildozer.spec file, I tried installing the ndk version r26b, version ndk21e, extracted it in the .buildozer, then downloads folder. Tried specifying the path for the ndk in the buildozer.spec file, but it was fruitless. Someone please help.

Comment: "Everything failed" is nothing we can work with here. Please edit your question and include more details what NDK you have downloaded, where you have extracted it to, and what output and errors you get when you execute the build process.

Comment: @Robert I edited it specifying. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.